# Inheriting From Specialized Template Struct/Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, template-specialization

Is it possible to inherit a specialized struct/class like following?

```
template<class TKey, class TData>
struct Container
{
    virtual void Add(TKey key, TData data) = 0;
};

template<class TData>
struct Container<int, TData>
{
    virtual void Add(int key, TData data) = 0;
};

struct TicketContainer : public Container<std::string>
{
    void Add(int key, std::string data)
    {
    }
};
```

I am getting errors in `TicketContainer` declaration complaining too few template parameters declared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
struct TicketContainer : public Container<std::string>
```

to:

```
struct TicketContainer : public Container<int, std::string>
```

or some other type for `TKey`.

Even though you have provided a partial specialization of `Container` you still need to specify both of the template parameters.

You can specify default types for template parameters if you do not want to specify both template parameters. In this case, you would have to reorder `TKey` and `TValue`  (which may be counter intuitive as associative containers are normally declared `key` then `value`):

```
// Reordered 'TData' and 'TKey'.
template<class TData, class TKey = int>
struct Container
{
    virtual void Add(TKey key, TData data) = 0;
};

template<class TData>
struct Container<TData> // Equivalent to 'struct Container<TData, int>'
{
    // This specialization seems pointless as it defines no
    // special behaviour.
    virtual void Add(int key, TData data) = 0;
};

struct TicketContainer : public Container<std::string>
{
};
```

Comment: Good tip on rearranging template parameters, if I can't use it here, it's still good to know. I was hoping partial specialization would remove burden of specifying already defined (specialized with) template parameter.

Comment: No, it won't. It means that when the specialized type is specified for `Container` it will choose the partially specialized implementation (which in this case, there is no special behaviour).